# ASP.net Windows Authentication with custom database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, windows-authentication

I'm creating an intranet website that requires Windows Authentication. I already set up everything, or I think I did, to use windows authentication and roles managed in a database. That's important because I can't use the Active Directory groups and roles.

It works. When I enter the website it display my Windows user name and it is accesible with `User.Identity.Name`. I can validate a role using `User.IsInRole("roleName")` and it works too.

Now the problem I have is that when I use `Membership.GetUser` and `Membership.GetAllUsers` I always get null and an empty collection.

My RoleManager Provider is:

```
<add 
name="SqlRoleManager" 
type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
applicationName="/appName" 
/>
```

And my Membership Provider is this one:

```
<add 
name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
applicationName="/appName" 
/>
```

Am I missing something or my config is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the default membership provider?

Comment: And I believe there is one / too much inside application name

Comment: Check this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Comment: Hi. How I do set the defualt provider?

Comment: Inside web config <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
      userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
Check the link I have posted!

Comment: I just did, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to call Membership.GetUser?  You are already authenticated via Windows Authentication.  If you want to use Membership with Windows Authentication (why, i don't know), you have to jump through some more hoops.

You can use the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, rather than SqlMembershipProvider.  This lets you call GetUser and retrieve AD information.

You can copy the Windows Authentication information into a SqlMembership database on login.

You can create a custom membership provider that allows you to do all the authentication yourself.

So, the first question is why do you want to use Membership?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.

I don't use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider because, as far I understand, it is for using Active Directory groups which I don't need and I can't modify.

About using Membership I know I already managed to login with windows authentication, but I want to use `Membership.GetUser` to get the UserId of the current user, thing I can't do with `User.Identity` or IPrincipal. Right now I get the UserId with an extra query to the database using the user name, but it just look wrong as Membership is supposed to help with those methods.

Comment: What do you mean with copying Windows Auth. information into the database?

About creating a custom membership... well I have no idea about how to create a new one and still using Windows Auth. With that I mean just displaying the current Windows user without asking any password nor having to manage it.

Comment: @Sheol - No.  ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider is about authentication only.  You use the WindowsTokenRoleProvider to provide the AD groups from AD.  If you are using SqlRoleProvider and ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider then it will do what you want.